# How to navigate URL after moving drupal site from one server to other server?

Tags: migrations

I have just moved my drupal 7 website from one server to other server.
But after moving it i am not bale to see any css effect and not able to open naviagte any link. I am using linux server.

Can somebody suggest how to do this.

Comment: Comments have been deleted. Please don't use them for extended discussion. Add the relevant information in the question.

Comment: Yes, the first thing to check is the value of `$base_url`, which just needs to be the URL of the site. URLs can contain a domain name (drupal.stackexchange.com) or an IP (127.0.0.1). Drupal documentation explain well how to set `$base_url`. For the rest, we cannot suggest much as debugging a site for which we don't have access is not possible.

Comment: And a URL starts with the protocol type (e.g. http://, https://, ftp://).

Comment: I have already provided same information but OP unable to understand. I have suggested same which you have mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of problems (after transfer to a new host) might be caused by some type of permission problems. Some of the extra comments from the OPer in the question makes me believe that is the case here also.

So I'd verify that the userid of your webserver has appropriate file permissions.

Another option is to verify the various items mentioned in the community documentation about [Migrating a site](https://www.drupal.org/node/776864). One of the typical issues is (as mentioned in this link):

> Attempt to log on to the new site. You will probably find that you are locked out by a combination of site maintenance mode and the non-clean URLs. In that case navigate to newsite/?q=user to login, then turn on clean URLs.